# Golang Example of jsonrpc over WebSocket?

Tags: go, websocket, json-rpc

Does anyone have a working example they can share of both client and server for a golang jsonrpc (1 or 2 is fine) + websocket implementation?  The docs seem a little thin in this area. I managed to get jsonrpc2 over http to work, but getting the websocket combination to work is getting away from me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have an example for you.
But you might try the nhooyr.io/websocket package's Net.Conn wrapper.

https://pkg.go.dev/nhooyr.io/websocket#NetConn

> It's for tunneling arbitrary protocols over WebSockets. Few users of the library will need this but it's tricky to implement correctly and so provided in the library. See https://github.com/nhooyr/websocket/issues/100.

The linked issue contains more details.

The golang x/net/websocket package [actually recommends you use nhooyr/websocket](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/websocket#pkg-overview) since it is better maintained and more feature-full.